# Migration Toolkit for Application and Quarkus

Tags: migration, quarkus

I have a JavaEE application running on wildfly and I want to move to Quarkus. I did read about the migration toolkit for applications, having a tool to analyze the code and estimate the required effort looked very handy.
I have a question about the result though: as far as I know, Quarkus does not support EJBs, but the tool doesn't mention it in the list of issues. It does have a section "EJBs", where I can see the list of all EJBs in my application, but that's it. Since an app with EJBs won't work properly, shouldn't that be an issue? Did I misunderstand how the report works?

Marco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaEE to Quarkus is not a migration path provided from [Migration Toolkit for Applications (MTA) 5.1](https://developers.redhat.com/products/mta/download).

MTA currently supports some specific migrations path towards Quarkus:

- from Spring Boot to Quarkus
- from Quarkus to Quarkus for version upgrades

The former is based on the Spring Boot API compatibility layer provided by Quarkus and, beside Spring Boot libraries, MTA identifies other libraries and frameworks that have a Quarkus extensions.
For example, a Spring Boot application that uses Apache Avro will get suggestions on how to migrate Spring Boot and Apache Avro.

The latter is based on Quarkus migration guides https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guides.
The currently supported update paths are for updating from Quarkus 1.10 towards latest.

The full list of avaliable migration paths is available at https://developers.redhat.com/products/mta/use-cases